# Handling UTF-8 string in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

We are using some third-party php library functions and have some difficulties converting utf-8 strings.

After some experiment, this is what we got so far:

(1) The following will print the *correct* unicode word (it's 'one' word) in browser(we use Firefox):

```
$s = "\345\244\247";
echo $s;

大 <-- (prints out a correct unicode word)
```

(2) However, the library function will return something like this:

```
$s2 = "\\345\\244\\247";
echo $s2;

\345\244\247  <-- the print out will contain escape character so the unicode isn't showing correctly
```

(3) So the question is, is there a php function capable of doing this, converting $s2 to the correct unicode form (like $s)?

Thanks.

The environment is PHP 5.3.

Comment: If the only problem is the double \\ you can set $s2 = str_replace("\\","\",$s2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like http://ideone.com/Owl2a3 :

```
function _conv($oct) {
    return chr(octdec($oct[1]));
}

$es = "\\345\\244\\247";
$es = preg_replace_callback('@\\\\(\d{3})@', '_conv', $es);

echo $es;
```

outputs `大`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, that you're escaping the slashes!

use this:

```
$s2 = str_replace("\\","\",$s2);
```

Comment: That won't change anything. By that time, the string contains the text with the \ - it is no longer a literal that PHP interprets.